# Android Service getting closed

Tags: android

i am creating a automatic wallpaper changing app but i am facing a problem that when i close the app from the task manager/recent apps, the service is getting closed. Here is my service code

```
public class WallpaperChange extends Service implements Runnable {

    private int WallpaperId[]={R.drawable.wallpaper1,R.drawable.wallpaper2};
    //to store user selected time
    private int time;

    //declare a flag to check which image to display next
    private int FLAG=0;

    private Thread t;

    //declare two Bitmap objects to store the wallpaper images

    Bitmap bitmap1,bitmap2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flag, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this,"New Time has been set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

        time=bundle.getInt("time");

        //initialize the bitmap objects with the wallpaper images
        bitmap1= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),WallpaperId[0]);
        bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),WallpaperId[1]);

        t=new Thread(WallpaperChange.this);
        t.start();
    //i tried Service.START_STICKY in place of 0
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service being destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if(FLAG==0) {
                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap1);
                    FLAG++;
                }
                else
                {
                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap2);
                    FLAG--;
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000*time);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i do not want to use foreground. isn't it possible without foreground??

Comment: If you close app it means that whole process will be destroyed including your service. I believe it would be better for you to use JobScheduler with JobService descendant with some interval.

Comment: then what is the use of service if it is getting destroyed. we use service for background process. As i know if we destroy the app, the service should not be destroyed. correct me if i am wrong. i am beginner to android.

Comment: "Background" here do not means "immortal", as service is the part of process. You can try to launch your service in separate process, but I'm not sure whether it will work as you expect - I haven't prior experience with such kind of services. You can get more here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: ok thanks bro. i will try with jobservice as well